# How to rotate a triangle in the direction it is moving?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have some triangles on canvas and they are randomly moving around the canvas according to given velocity.
It is similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_building_practice) exercise but triangles instead of circles.

```
draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    const angle = Math.atan2(this.velY,this.velX);
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x+10,this.y+10);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x-10,this.y+10);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

I tried this and it's having no effect whatsoever

here's how I am using the function

```
while(boids.length < 250){
    boid = new Boid(
        random(10,canvas.width-10),
        random(10,canvas.height-10),
        random(-5,5),
        random(-5,5)
    )
    boids.push(boid);
}

function animate(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(17 17 17)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for(const boid of boids){
        boid.draw();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

`boid` is a class with members, `x`,`y`,`velX`,`velY`.

Comment: Where did you get that code from? You probably wanna check what [`restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) does and how it works. And remember, the canvas context is a state machine. The various drawing operations are affected by the settings that are set at the time they're called.

Comment: "I tried this and its having no effect whatsoever" -- did you ever call the `draw()` function? Please share your whole code.

Comment: @ggorlen ofcourse I am calling it. `draw()` method draws the object but I can't manage to rotate it according to the velocity (`velX` & `velY` ).

Comment: Please show how you're calling it. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: @Kaiido I think I am going to have to use the state functions but in my current code its having no effect. I tried playing with the values of x and y but nothing gave preferred result

Comment: `ctx.restore();` should be at the end, and remove `this.x`/`this.y` from the line funcs.

Comment: @ggorlen there is something weird with the `translate(this.x,this.y);` and then `ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y);`  I could not figure that mix out... if we already translated by that amount why do we need to move by that much again?? ... I think that is just a mistake, see my second sample code below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try drawing triangles without using rotate or translate...

Just a bit of trigonometry math:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawTriangle(center, size, angle, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    a = angle * Math.PI / 180
    x = center.x + size * Math.sin(a)
    y = center.y + size * Math.cos(a)
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    angle += 120
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
}

colors = ["cyan", "blue", "red"]
for (let i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
  drawTriangle({ x: i * 30, y: 50 }, i*8, i*19, colors[i % 3])
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=120></canvas>
```

On this case I'm using equilateral triangles, but you can use any others once you play around with the math, if it confuses you might want to start here:
https://study.com/skill/learn/how-to-inscribe-an-equilateral-triangle-in-a-circle-explanation.html

---

If you insist on using rotate and translate, here is an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(x, y, velY, velX) {
  const angle = Math.atan2(velY, velX);

  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(10, 10);
  ctx.lineTo(-10, 10);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}


draw(20, 10, 10, 10)
draw(40, 10, 30, 10)
draw(60, 10, 10, 30)
draw(80, 10, 0, 180)
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width=300 height=120></canvas>
```

My approach here is to translate and rotate then draw our triangle right at that position then undo the rotation and translate  to go back to the starting position, you can see that I'm drawing four triangles with different angles and they are spaced at an increment of 20 on the X axis.

Comment: It worked, I thought I must use `ctx.restore()` to undo it. Tweaked some x,y values and it's perfect, thanks and thanks for the resource.